# Ping packet loss 100

Tags: networking, ping, cable

I'm using a laptop in a dormitory and I was trying to go to a website, but it only shows texts and white background. When I check another website about the same thing happens, no pics just texts and black background. When I open my twitter I can't see my own profile photo as well as my other friends.

After I do a ping check it shows something like this:

```
packets transmitted   9

received              0

packet loss           100 %

time                  8000 ms
```

I'm using a direct connection (cable) and no wi-fi router. And I've just pinged google from my command prompt and it doesn't end even after I closed my command prompt. Is something wrong with my connection?

Comment: Since it isn't working, something must be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by the ping doesn't end? Did you set `/t` ?

Comment: @Alvin Laurentius: Is it possible to try a different network cable?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [tranparent proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy), usually it can transfer [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) and [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp) protocols. It's alright.

If you want to use ping ([ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) protocol) only one way - find your system administrator.